# Separator or spacer in Richfaces 4.37

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Is in Richfaces 4.37 or JSF2 separator or spacer which shows horizontal visible line?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, but you can just make a `<div>` and style its top border.

```
<div style="width: 100%; border-top: 2px solid black"></div>
```

This is how it was done in RichFaces 3 except the div was using a background image.

Comment: @BalusC Depends on where it's going to be used, I guess. But as far as I understand hr has some cross-browser issues when it comes to styling.

Comment: Only if you consider IE6 a browser.